# Decoding the unknown objects back to original form in swift

Tags: ios, swift, decode, encode

I have RAWJSON Class which Used to store and operate objects of unknown structure that's not possible to decode.

```
public indirect enum RawJSON: Codable, Hashable {
    case number(Double)
    case string(String)
    case bool(Bool)
    case dictionary([String: RawJSON])
    case array([RawJSON])
    case `nil`

    static let double = number

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let singleValueContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode(Double.self) {
            self = .number(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode([String: RawJSON].self) {
            self = .dictionary(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode([RawJSON].self) {
            self = .array(value)
            return
        } else if singleValueContainer.decodeNil() {
            self = .nil
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError
            .dataCorrupted(
                DecodingError
                    .Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Could not find reasonable type to map to JSONValue")
            )
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case let .number(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .bool(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .string(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .array(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .dictionary(value): try container.encode(value)
        case .nil: try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}

public extension RawJSON {
    func dictionary(with value: RawJSON?, forKey key: String) -> RawJSON? {
        guard case var .dictionary(content) = self else { return nil }
        content[key] = value
        return .dictionary(content)
    }
}
public indirect enum RawJSON: Codable, Hashable {
    case number(Double)
    case string(String)
    case bool(Bool)
    case dictionary([String: RawJSON])
    case array([RawJSON])
    case `nil`

    static let double = number

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let singleValueContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode(Double.self) {
            self = .number(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode([String: RawJSON].self) {
            self = .dictionary(value)
            return
        } else if let value = try? singleValueContainer.decode([RawJSON].self) {
            self = .array(value)
            return
        } else if singleValueContainer.decodeNil() {
            self = .nil
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError
            .dataCorrupted(
                DecodingError
                    .Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Could not find reasonable type to map to JSONValue")
            )
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case let .number(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .bool(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .string(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .array(value): try container.encode(value)
        case let .dictionary(value): try container.encode(value)
        case .nil: try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}

public extension RawJSON {
    func dictionary(with value: RawJSON?, forKey key: String) -> RawJSON? {
        guard case var .dictionary(content) = self else { return nil }
        content[key] = value
        return .dictionary(content)
    }
}
```

I want the array of string in its original form.

how can i decode it to original array of strings?

```
let RAWJSONArray = [RawJSON.string("A"),RawJSON.string("B"),RawJSON.string("C")]
        let arrayString : [String] = []
        for item in RAWJSONArray {
            arrayString.append(item) <-- error No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'  
        }
```

I used this class from streamchat API using client to client chat they store extra data and convert it to RAWJSON type object and send it to the API.

Comment: And what if it's not `RawJSON.string` in `RAWJSONArray`? Else, you can use a `switch`, or `if case let` to get the associated value of the enum and append it to the array of String. "I want the array of string in its original form as when log it shows me": That's unclear, do you have an example of what you want?

Comment: i want to append the value of string stored in RAWJSONArray to the "arrayString" array of strings.

Comment: You mean this: https://pastebin.com/KqCZScGg ?

Comment: you are right this is also fine but why we cannot compare string value after decoding the item?
Most of cases where i am getting userIDs array or the other data will not be able to compare like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
var arrayString : [String] = []
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

for item in RAWJSONArray {
    if let data = try? encoder.encode(item),
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {             
       arrayString.append(str)
    }
}
```

or perhaps you literally want the strings only?

```
for case let .string(str) in RAWJSONArray {
    arrayString.append(str)
}
```